# Prove or disprove continuity of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

I'm preparing for a test and there is a question that I don't how to solve. I tried to prove the statement and to find a counterexample, but nothing worked...

The question is:

> Let $f(x)$ be a function in the domain $(a,b)$. Prove or disprove - if $\displaystyle g(x)=\max_{t\in(a,x)}f(t)$ is continuous in the domain $(a,b)$, then $f(x)$ is also continuous in this domain.

I will appreciate any kind of help, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In $\;(0,1)\;$ , take

$$D(x):=\begin{cases}1&,\;\;x\in\Bbb Q\\{}\\0&,\;\;x\notin\Bbb Q\end{cases}\;\;\implies g(x):=\max_{t\in (0,x)}D(x)=1\;\;,\;\;\forall\,x\in (0,1)$$

Answer (score 3):

This is not true. Think about $f:(0,2)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$f(x)=\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
    1, & \hbox{for $0<x<1$;} \\
    0, & \hbox{for $1\leq x<2$.}
  \end{array}
\right.$$
Then $f$ is not continuous, but $g(x)=1$ for all $x\in(0,2)$, which is continuous.